# sftp via bash script in a cronjob: 'get' and 'rm' commands not found?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp, expect

I'm trying to do something real, real simple: download a file from a sftp site at a set time. However, I'm getting errors like 'command: rm does not exist' or 'command  get does not exist' which is garbage, because these commands obviously exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#remove current version of file
rm -f /home/user/downloads/data/newdata.zip

spawn sftp user@ftpsite.com
expect "password:"
send "PaSsWoRd\n"
expect "sftp>"
get /mycompany/myproject/data/newdata.zip /home/user/downloads/data
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact

(base) root@ubuntu:~# ./shellscript.sh
invalid command name "rm"
    while executing
"rm -f /home/user/downloads/data/newdata.zip"
```

or without the removal

```
(base) root@ubuntu:~# sudo ./shellscript.sh
spawn sftp user@sftpsite.com
EFT Server Login - %DATE% %TIME% - Please enter valid credentials to continueEnter password: 
Connected to ftpsite.com
sftp> invalid command name "get"
    while executing
"get /mycompany/myproject/data/newdata.zip /home/user/downloads/data"
```

What gives? Why can't I get real error messages - I'm sure get and rm a perfectly fine commands and I can verify this by running them directly from the command line, where they work fine.

Comment: The script begins with `#!/usr/bin/expect` so it should contain Expect commands, not shell commands.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the difference?

Comment: It needs to be `send "get ..."`

Comment: They're completely different languages. Expect is a scripting language for controlling another interactive program using `expect` and `send` commands.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great explanation, and guy below's code worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing TCL code in an Expect script. You are not writing Bash in a shell script.

You have to `send` the commands you want to write to the sftp tool:

```
send "get /mycompany/myproject/data/newdata.zip /home/user/downloads/data\n"
```

And `exec` any commands you want to run non-interactively:

```
exec rm -f /home/user/downloads/data/newdata.zip
```